# Можно ли использовать Python вместо JS в программной реализации сайта?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-3.x

Решил, раз уж надо учить веб-фреймворк для Python, то и Css с Html было бы неплохо подтянуть. И тут -  JavaScript

Я коне-что понимаю, что скорее всего его придётся учить, но можно ли использовать Python вместо JS, чтобы сделать программную реализацию сайта?

Comment: Если коротко: для фронтэнда - нет, используйте javascript, typescript или kotlin (последние два все равно при выкатывании на сайт транслируются в javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко: да. Сайт проекта: -> https://pyscript.net/

Документация -> https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/

Github проекта -> https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript

PyScript позволяет запускать код Python прямо в браузере, предоставляя возможность программировать без инфраструктурных барьеров.

Comment: Но всё же лучше для начала изучить JS. Что бы появилось общее понимание.

Comment: Во-первых PyScript сам по себе секунды 4 стартует (скачивает webassembly и инициализируется), по крайней мере в текущей реализации, не в экспериментальном micropython варианте. Во-вторых под js есть куча фреймворков, под PyScript придется свои велосипеды городить. Так что PyScript на данный момент можно рассматривать разве что как интересную штуку, с которой можно поэкспериментировать, но не использовать в реальных проектах.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Но это такой себе вариант. Нативная разработка для динамики на сайте - js. Т.е. движок внутри браузера работает только с js. Pyscript и подобные решения берут ваш код на python и транслируют в js. При этом итоговый js код получается очень неоптимизированным. JS разработали за неделю, вы его очень быстро сможете выучить. Кроме того, есть очень популярные фреймворки по типу React. И в них только js. Резюмируя, изучение Pyscript и подобных решений приведёт вас в тупик.

Comment: PyScript не транслируется в js. "JS разработали за неделю" - вот это интересно, где вы такое прочитали, и как это влияет на скорость изучения.

Comment: Ну вы в тегах <py-script/> пишите python код, и он выполняется через js. Касательно недели я ошибся, но я имел ввиду, что js можно за неделю изучить на достаточно хорошем уровне, чтобы не заниматься фигнёй по типу PyScript

Comment: Он не выполняется через js, он выполняется через подгружаемый низкоуровневый [WebAssembly](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) (WASM) модуль, потенциально может выполняться не медленнее чем js (но это уже зависит от оптимизаций этого модуля).

Answer (score 0):

ну как сказать... на бэке? точно да, его делай на чём душе угодно.

фронт? нуууу... ответ довольно таки вариативный

- ворвавшись на фронт с двух ног, вообще без какого либо взаимодействия с js - нет
- с подключением js либ? наверное да, выше насоветовали всякого разного, но ручаться за те либы не могу.
- с ручным использованием js уже да, WebAssembly в помощь. если верить диаграмме которую видел, WA активируется только из js и всё что угодно в него заливается тоже только через js, хуже того он и работает почти как плагин для js(WA не имеет прямого доступа к чему либо кроме js'а, разве что выполняется в отдельных потоках и то хз, не проверял).

т.е. использовать его(WA) стоит только для тех видов вычислений в которых js точно сливает вожделенному ЯП. ну или когда нужно получить дополнительный(е) поток(и), дабы фронт не повис наглухо. в остальных случаях лучше изучить js и не париться.

конечно, js за немного недель создали как заметили выше, только та окаменелость из 90х годов и современный js общего имеют только название. по части логики и синтаксиса свежий крайне приятен.

> Я **коне-что** понимаю

звучит занятно =)